# react native: attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I create a React ref by calling React.createRef in React Native. Then I  assign it to a ref. I got the error: Attempted to assign to readonly property

```js
export default class List extends PureComponent<Props, object> {

  private flatListRef: React.RefObject<FlatList<any>>;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.flatListRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      /.../
      <FlatList ref={this.flatListRef}></FlatList>
    )
  }
}
```

But When I use the callback way to assign the react ref, everything is ok.

```
<FlatList ref={ele => { this.flatListRef = ele }}></FlatList>
```

I have no idea what's the difference between the two ways

Comment: Check out this article I found on the topic that might help: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/react-refs-with-typescript-a32d56c4d315 Also it might help to add the typescript tag to your question

Answer (score 0):

the `ref` property in React is expecting a function and it's called immediately after the component is mounted. You can do other things besides setting a reference.

https://zhenyong.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute